# Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint - value conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I get this error when executing the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    sub.[IP Address],
    sub.IPAddressToInteger,
    bt.Subnet
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         [IP Address],
         [dw].[IPAddressToInteger] ([IP Address]) AS IPAddressToInteger
     FROM 
         dw.vw_Device dd
     WHERE 
         [IP Address] <> NULL) sub
LEFT JOIN 
    dw.btdiamond bt ON sub.IPAddressToInteger BETWEEN bt.startipaddressinteger AND bt.endipaddressinteger
```

The query uses function which converts IP Address to integer.

This allows to match IP Address to Subnet.

I guess the reason of this error maybe [IP Address] contains values as NULL, +, -, etc.

How can select all the rows where the error occurs?

End then how to get rid of these errors?

**Update:**
Here is the funtion:[Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pV3B.png)

Comment: It seems the error is originated from the function [dw].[IPAddressToInteger] (which I cannot see)...I suppose it simply returns the sum-product of ip parts: if it is so, try to use TRY-CATCH [see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  to return NULL when there is the error...in this way you can catch invalid rows using a simple WHERE sub.IPAddressToInteger IS NULL.

Comment: An IPv6 address is represented as eight groups of four hexadecimal digits (i.e. containing some letters in addition to colons)  Are you dealing with IPv6 addresses?

Comment: **nb** This will **NOT** work `WHERE [IP Address]<>NULL` you MUST use `WHERE [IP Address] IS NOT NULL` ...... `=` or `<>` or `!=` cannot evaluate NULL because NULL is indeterminate and hence cannot be equal, or not equal, use **IS NULL** or **IS NOT NULL**

Comment: I am dealing with IPv4. Even if I remove [IP Address]<>NULL still get the error.

Comment: I have added a screen shot of the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you need... If you want a function that doesn't go to pot over unexpected characters, you'll need to post the function code.
If you want to be able to identify rows that have unexpected characters, so you can fix them... You can use something like the following...

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    dbo.BaseTable bt
WHERE 
    bt.IP_Address LIKE '%[^0-9.]%';
```

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the function. In almost all rows I have a dot "." Dot is not a problem. Other characters are

Comment: @Bartek, I know... The code posted above will identify rows that have characters other than numbers or "dot".